# URL 404s looking for index.php in a subdirectory (.htaccess)

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

Hey I am trying to link to a subdirectory and have index.php in that directory load, but it is returning a 404 not found error. The file structure is this:

```
| index.php
| .htaccess
| subfolder
     | index.php
     | about.php
```

When I go to `mysite.com/subfolder`, I want the index.php there to load. I know the problem is with my .htaccess file because when I remove it the URL works. Here is the code in .htaccess:

```
Options +MultiViews

# Remove file extensions from page names

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# Disable Index Listing
Options -Indexes
```

My guess is that because I'm removing file extensions, the server is looking for `mysite/subfolder.php` and can't find it so it 404s. I'm new to .htaccess files, however, and they're still very cryptic to me. Searching online has a lot of code but doesn't explain how anything works. Any ideas on how to fix this issue and why the fix works would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are enabling `MultiViews` option then you don't need a rewrite rule to handle extensions.

Just keep these lines in your .htaccess:

```
Options +MultiViews
DirectorySlash On

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

And remove everything else. Then test with `mysite.com/subfolder/` URL